# Does Python's pyodbc support server side cursor (for Netezza)?

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc, netezza

I need to query a Netezza database using Python. There are tens of millions of matched rows so I am currently running out of memory before my query can complete. I see that a server-side cursor can be used with psycopg2, but I don't see a way to connect to my Netezza database using psycopg2 or a way to change the pyodbc connection I create to use a server-side cursor.

My connection and query currently looks like:

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect(dsn='NZSQL;SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+uid+';PWD='+pw)
cur = conn.cursor()
data = pd.read_sql('Select * from table join table2 on table1.var1=table2.var2', conn)
```

Is it possible to use a server-side cursor with Netezza in Python? If not, any suggested workarounds?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the `chunksize` argument for `read_sql`?

Comment: Using `chuncksize` seems to work when my query doesn't require joining the large tables.  When I generated the data chunk-wise and assembled the full dataframe from the individual pieces afterwards, it worked, but once I try a query that requires joining the tables, the whole dataframes are still simply too large to fit in memory and the join needs to be executed on the full datasets, rather than chunks.

Comment: You could still run the joined query and output by chunks, e.g. `data = pd.read_sql('SELECT a.*, b.* FROM table1 AS a INNER JOIN table2 AS b ON a.field=b.field', conn, chunksize=1000)`. The join will happen on the server side, so you wouldn't have to worry about memory overflow, and you will get the joined results as chunks to your local machine.